# Undefined Index in PHP _ non compound name

Tags: php, variables, syntax-error, undefined

1. `Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'error_reporting' has no effect in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHPfolder/file.php on line 3`
2. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHPfolder/file.php on line 3`

Before it was showing , 
Unidentified Index in   same line no.

As I added `use error_reporting(0);`
The Output generated successfully.

Please help to solve the above mentioned errors `1` and `2`.

Comment: please post the `/opt/lampp/htdocs/PHPfolder/file.php` code

Answer (score 1):

It should be just `error_reporting(0);`

`use` is for [namespases](http://php.net/namespaces) not for settings